# c# Response.Redirect in RowCommand issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a Redirect in Row command as follows

```
 if (e.CommandName == "GoToTask")
            {
                Response.Redirect(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "~/Secure/WorkTasksDetails.aspx?WorkTasksId={0}", new Guid(e.CommandArgument.ToString())));
            }
```

This works fine, it opens the required page in a new tab.

The problem is that when going back to the original page and using any control that causes a post back, it opens another new tab?!?!

Can't figure how to stop this.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to see if your `e.CommandName == "GoToTask"` is true everytime?

Comment: please add tags to your question and minimum code for reproducing the problem

Comment: When going back to the original page I usually choose the filter button that does another post back function. The breakpoint is not hit again this time but a new tab is opened. I need to point out that the "extra" tab page is not the one requested that works properly but the reposted filtered page, ie the original that contains the grid with the row command.

Comment: @PaulCarey, since you didn't include the code you're using for generating that form all I can do is guessing. My guess is that `Response.Redirect()` is changing the url in your Internet Browser and after you go back and post again, page is submitting to a different url. Also I'm wondering if the `~` symbol is being replaced by webapplication root. Things to check are server side code that generates form and all relevant javascript code.

Comment: Hi derloopkat
Haven't included all the code as it is far too large. other than that a page load If(!IsPostBack) is the only other code accessed other than the filter that simply populates athe grid. No redirect is ever hit after the intial request but it continues to open new tabs no matter what. I appreciate that a whole working page would be far batter but there's not enough space and without DB access it wont work anyways. Just hoping someone had come across this behaviour before.

Comment: @PaulCarey, unless you can reproduce the problem and post relevant code here, I doubt someone will be able to help. It might be something like `<asp:LinkButton ID="lblUser" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.open('ViewJob.aspx?ID=432', '_blank');" Text="VIEW JOB" />` in an aspx file.